# Як "клепка" стала "розумом"?

Tags: етимологія, іменники, фразеологізми

От є фразеологізм *"не мати клепки в голові"*, що означає *не мати розуму, бути дурнуватим*. Про це читаємо навіть у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/klepka).

Якщо ж прочитати саме значення слова "клепка", бачимо:

> **КЛЕ́ПКА**, и, жін. *Кожна з опуклих дощечок, з яких складається бочка, діжка й т. ін.* Ой у полі озеречко, Там плавало відеречко, Соснові клепки, а дубове денце (Народна лірика, 1956, 261).

Отож цікавить, яким чином народ провів аналогію *дощечка = розум*, звідки було утворено фразеологізм **"не мати клепки в голові"**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Багато фразеологізмів мають глибоке коріння у давньому побуті. Фразеологізм «не мати клепки в голові» походить з  [бондарської термінології](http://schoollib.com.ua/ukr_lang/1/57.html). Слово **клепка** увійшло до численної сім'ї стійких висловів для характеристики розумових здібностей людини: без третьої (сьомої, дванадцятої) клепки (клепок), без клепки в голові, без клепки в тім'ї, не вистачає (бракує) однієї (третьої, десятої) клепки в голові, розсохлися клепки (в кого), позбутися клепки, вставити клепки (клепку) (кому).

Цікаве тлумачення знаходимо у статті  [Подвійна актуалізація фразеологізмів](http://dn.khnu.km.ua/dn/k_default.aspx?M=k0914&T=04_4&lng=1&st=0)

> У контексті з поезії В.Кравчука Кричала Бочка без упину:/ Захочу – море я поглину./ Для неї моря було мало,/ У бочки клепки бракувало актуалізаторами фразеологізму «бракує клепки», зі значенням ‘хто-небудь розумово обмежений, ненормальний’ є сполучення лексем «захочу – море переплину», «для неї моря було мало», що свідчать про безглузді прагнення Бочки. Актуалізатором етимона ФО є лексема «бочка». Ця лексема – гіперонім до компонента етимона ФО «клепка». У бочки дійсно може бракувати клепки, це її деталь, таким чином словосполучення «клепки бракувало» сприймається у буквальному значенні. Водночас вираз «у бочки клепки бракувало» є своєрідною згорнутою експлікацією образної основи фразеологізму «бракує клепки», адже він є натяком на вихідне образне уявлення, ситуацію, що стала базою виникнення фразеологізму.

Отже, можна зробити висновок, що бочка складається з дощечок,  а коли якоїсь бракує, то бочка неповноцінна. Так само, коли людина розумово обмежена, то її чогось бракує, тому виникло таке порівняння. Детальнішої етимології в Етимологічному словнику немає.